# How to efficiently update a Keras variable slice?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, tf.keras

Suppose we have `x = K.zeros((4, 6))`, and we wish to add 1 to row 0: `x[0] += 1`. The variable is created via `Layer`'s [`add_weight()`](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/master/keras/engine/base_layer.py#L250) w/ `training=False`, so it isn't updated via backprop. What is the most *speed-efficient* way to do so?

[Relevant Git](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/36559)

---

**Context**: I'm implementing recurrent batch normalization, with `moving_mean` and `moving_variance` variables distinct for each timestep in an RNN - each thus having a shape of `(units, timesteps)`. The goal is to update one `timesteps` slice per step via `K.moving_average_update()`. One approach is as follows:

```py
import keras.backend as K
units, timesteps = 4, 6
x = K.zeros((units, timesteps), dtype='float32', name='x')

x_new = x[:units, 0].assign(K.ones((units,), dtype='float32'))  # dummy example
K.set_value(x, K.get_value(x_new))
print(K.get_value(x))
```

```py
[[1. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [1. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [1. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [1. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]]
```

Looks good - except, a *new copy* of `x` was created. In practice, we can have `timesteps > 100` (e.g. 120), so we are creating an array 120x larger than it needs to be, 120 times (1 / step), making it an `O(timesteps**2)` operation - as opposed to usual slicing, `O(timesteps)`. Inspecting Keras' [Backend](https://keras.io/backend/), its `update_` methods all involve copying the original array.

Is there anything more efficient in Keras? If not, in TensorFlow?

---

**Note**: I'm aware of the "append to list* then assign via array at last step" alternative, which *is* a lot more efficient, but we can do better - at least as in terms of 'traditional' arrays (* *or* fill zeros-array). Though admittedly, there's also the GPU factor, which works better in batch-assignments than iterative - but I cannot benchmark latter effectively per what I described.

Comment: Isn't `x` already updated when you do `assign`? If `x_new` has the entire shape, the system is very probably intepreting it right?

Comment: @DanielMöller It isn't; `print(K.get_value(x))` after `x.assign()` returns the original `x`.

Comment: Hmm... you could try to concatenate a new strip with an old big slice, not sure if it's better, but it's an option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured out direct slice-update:

```py
x_slice = x[4:5]
x_slice.assign(math_ops.sub(x_slice, some_tensor))
```

`x_slice` appears to nicely reference the original tensor array; for some reason, `assign_sub` fails at this; see [clarifying comment](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/36559#issuecomment-588184593).